# FormAssembly: Custom JavaScript to Launch Credit Card Section Conditionally if Total Cost > 0

Tags: javascript, forms, salesforce

I am not a programmer. I work for a nonprofit. We're using FormAssembly integrated with Salesforce to run our membership intake system. A recent funding opportunity is allowing us to credit new memberships to their grantees. I successfully used the code in the FormAssembly support library to create a discount code that gives a 100% discount for the member, so they don't have to pay but they are still entered into our system fluidly. However, right now, the credit card fields are still required, and it's going to error if someone tries to buy anything with a CC for zero dollars. So, I want to make that section of fields conditionally appear if the total cost is greater than zero. FormAssembly can't help with custom code, but they provided us some code that another client used and told me I could try to modify it for my own purposes. I have been unsuccessful. Here is the original code:

```
function showPayment(amount){
    if(amount <= 0)
    {
      //Apply class names to your target section ID 
      //(e.g. tfa_2228,tfa_2229) to "hide" them
      document.getElementById("tfa_2228").className = "section offstate";
      document.getElementById("tfa_2229").className = "";
    }
    else if(amount > 0)
    {
      //This will turn the section "on"
      document.getElementById("tfa_2228").className = "section";
      document.getElementById("tfa_2229").className = "required";
    }
    return amount;
  }
```

Again - I am not a programmer. I tried to just swap out the "tfa_2228" with the element ID for my credit card section in FormAssembly, but that did nothing. I don't know what the other = " " sections in the code are referencing and if I need to change those or not. Or if there is some code missing here that I also need to include to make this work. I am sure this is a really basic question, but this stuff is not my forte (I'm the marketing person who has slowly gotten sucked into an ad-hock Salesforce Admin position over 3 years) and us being a nonprofit, I don't really know who I can ask as we don't have the budget for a programmer or fulltime IT person. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you posted a bit of code that could help you but we still have no idea how to apply it to your use case. Can you edit the question and post your actual form or at least the controlling field and the section with credit card? Or link if thee page is public? I've never touched FA in my life but this looks fairly vanilla JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I would love to help but this is missing a lot of context. I'll give you some guidance but it may not get you to a solution.

First, I don't know where that `showPayment` function is being called or if it is even being called. So let's check this by logging to the console. Replace the code with this...

```js
function showPayment(amount){
  console.log('I AM HERE!!!');
}
```

Go to wherever this form is running with this updated code and [open the browser console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/). You should see something like this...

[image]

> Disregard the `Script snippet %2325` filename

If you not see the console log above you should talk to the form assembly peeps because there could be many reasons for that.

If you can confirm the console log we can move on. The next thing is to explain what the example code is doing to empower you to debug it yourself.

The code `document.getElementById("tfa_2228")` is finding an element on the webpage by it's `id`. Then sets the class name or class of that element accordingly for the given condition. The classes of an element, among other things, assigns styles to an HTML element. So first I would go to your form and find the [id](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp) of the element(s) you want to hide/show, [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom/) might help.

Finally, you have the element id(s) you want to hide and show, now you can add them to their example code. The classes they provide are likely what you need but that is way out of context I cannot know how the classes will affect the look of your form. So it seems that it will work by just finding the correct id(s).

If all of that fails you could simply force the element(s) to be hidden using something like...

```js
function showPayment(amount) {
  if (amount <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("my-cc-form-input-id-1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("my-cc-form-input-id-2").style.display = "none";
  } else if (amount > 0) {
    document.getElementById("my-cc-form-input-id-1").style.display = "block"; // this could break the css
    document.getElementById("my-cc-form-input-id-2").style.display = "block";
  }
  return amount;
}
```

The main issue with this is reverting the display back because it could be one of many [values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

So with that, I hope a little trial and error gets you to a solution!